# Send money via paypal (iOS paypal sdk)

Tags: ios, paypal

I am working on an iOS app where the user can participate in a contest and win a cash prize. But I don't know how I can send this prize money to the user via paypal.

I am aware that this can be achieved using Chained/Parallel payments in Web, but it is not available for iOS.

Is there any way to achieve it in paypal iOS sdk or any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: FYI... This `may` be considered gambling, and you should check the laws in any area you plan on distributing this app.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes we are aware of it and will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

IOS SDK only supports commercial payments at the moment. If you need to send money, you could look into using Mass Pay API. You would just need to know the payee's email address.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Is iOS SDK supports mass API?

Comment: no it does not. You would need to make that call from your backend.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis. If we call it from backend , will Apple approve this kind of approach?? Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS sdk doesn't provide this functionality yet. I read it some where that it was scheduled for this year, but still nothing from them. 
For confirmation you may visit the,https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/. This clear states that only two modes of payment is supported.

For getting solution to your problem, you should consider MPL(mobile payment library) or the classic Api from paypal. Though you have option of rest api also but for now that is only available in USA. Using classic api you can do whatever you need to do. I had one application, recently, where i needed to do the chained payment, i hosted the web service over server in .net environment and passed the parameter to it in the query string, the logic implemented in web service takes user to the paypal login page and then user can do his transaction. You are targeting the mobile app, so you need to open the web service like in the web view from where you can do the transaction.

for the iOS policy you may refer to, developers.apple.com and by going into the policy or just google it. If you implement the flow clearly and gets approval of paypal then you can go ahead and can submit it to iOS store. By doing this you may have chance of getting approved, But i don't think apple will approve this app, they strangle recommend IAP for what you are trying to do. Let me know your thoughts in comments.